# Collection view cell slow detect selected item in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm putting the collection view into table view cell and I made it can display on the cell but when I want to select the collection cell (to change the color or print cell number), the select function is not working, I need to tap the cell many time to make it selected. Why the cell slow detect the selected item? What code will affect the cell to be selected?

This is the code for select the collection cell

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width/5, height: width/4)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
    collectionView?.delaysContentTouches = false

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
    cell.cateImg.image = imageName[indexPath.row]
    cell.cateLabel.text! = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell {
        cell.cateImg.image = imageName2[indexPath.row]
        print("collectionViewCell selected \(indexPath)")
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell {
        cell.cateImg.image = imageName[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

[image]

Project zip link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y10dgp3q61pi5n1/Finnciti.zip?dl=0

problem on AddViewCell.swift

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.  I'm having difficulty formulating the question.  Good luck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem after delete this code on AddViewController.

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddExpenseVC.dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to deselect this checkmark in Collection View properties

[image]

Comment: Tried, still cannot. I uploaded my project zip, maybe can find out the problem faster.

Comment: Didn't know that setting existed.  Thanks!

Comment: this is how you do it in code (swift): `collectionView.delaysContentTouches = false`

Answer (score 0):

In AddViewController you are adding gesture recognizer to the view, which make every user gesture to be detected by the tap recognizer. You can remove this gesture:

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddViewController.dismissKeyboard))
```

For dismissing keyboard you can implement tebleView delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dismissKeyboard()
    }
```